# How to block parts of a website

Tags: firewall, websites

I already use the hosts file to get rid of entire domains that are time sinks, but some websites that largely are wastes of time (eg reddit) have useful parts. So I'd like to allow www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer but block www.reddit.com/r/all.

Searching online I have a difficulty finding results that aren't simply editing the hosts file, and as far as I understand that only works for entire domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ad blocker like adblock plus in your browser,
and define rules to not load certain pages matching some pattern.

For this general approach, [Adblock plus firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) would work.

For the specific use case in your example:
Use the addon [LeechBlock-NG](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock-ng/), which is directly targeted at this.

In the review comments, you find an explicit configuration [for your exact case](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/reviews/613060/)
(The review question first states it does not work - but the answer explains it does work)

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, this is possible by setting up a proxy. I'm not too familiar with doing so, but found two recommendations, one for `squid` and one for `privoxy`.

A guide for doing this with `privoxy` can be found on superuser: [Block specific URL on web browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/393967/block-specific-url-on-web-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest an extension : Intention.
it lets me use facebook.com/programming-hero but not facebook.com/

It gives a promt to use just for 1 min , 5 min or custom or just to close my tab when i open facebook.com.

**I think it is the best website blocker for Focus increasing and Distraction free web.**